# Can AM–GM fail on a digital computer?

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It is well-known that valid mathematical formulas can fail on digital computers, due to rounding error, catastrophic cancellation, or whatever. So, it seems that the celebrated AM–GM inequality can also fail on a digital computer. So, can anyone supply such a fairly minimal and real-world-ly plausible scenario?

Comment: Not exactly a "minimal" example, but something will go wrong if $x$ and $y$ are so large that $xy$ overflows but $x+y$ doesn't.

Comment: How about using the fact that (on a binary computer, in floating-point) $$\frac{1}{3} * 3 \ne 1$$ to get your counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double x = 1.5;
    double y = 1.5000000000000002;
    printf("AM: %.16f\n", (x+y)/2);
    printf("GM: %.16f\n", sqrt(x*y));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc foo.c -lm`, run with `./a.out`; output is

```
AM: 1.5000000000000000
GM: 1.5000000000000002
```

This failure of AM/GM is due to rounding errors.

Here's the details of the analogous problem in decimal, where it's easier to follow: using floating-point representations, in decimal, with 3 digits of precision, rounding to nearest (and rounding to even for ties), we have
\begin{align*}
580\times 581 &= 336980 \approx 337000 \\
\sqrt{337000} &= 580.517\dots \approx 581
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
580+581 &= 1161 \approx 1160 \\
1160/2 &= 580
\end{align*}

Comment: (Oh, and the same example works in Python, and in Haskell, and probably anywhere IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point numbers are used.  I expect it'll even work in the Javascript console of the browser you're using right now.)

Comment: Bingo. Much thanks.